# HTML checkbox onclick not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code:

```
  <input name="SLSFrageFeld_Frage050016_Frage05001701" type="checkbox" onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='';" onclick=" return showSB();" onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow';"/>
```

However, when I click on the resulting checkbox, the event onclick is not being fired. I am testing it with IE11.

Comment: Seems to work fine ... https://jsfiddle.net/2de1zn2w/

Comment: @Alex-Mi Have u checked whether anything wrong with the function name, as I don't find any bug in your code and I have checked your code in IE11 using a simple alert statement.

Comment: Avoid inline events in favor of [element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener). Your code will be way more usable and maintainable with event listeners.

Comment: Your onclick attribute value changed with alert function and worked. I think your have different problem maybe your showSB() function doesn't find. Are you sure showSB() function correct name?

Comment: Remove `return`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by other HTML and JavaScript elements in the web-page. Sorry for this misunderstanding.